# Migrating from Courier-IMAP to Dovecot. Roundcube dom't get folders

Tags: imap, dovecot, roundcube, courier-imap

**Mission**: I'm trying to migrate from courier-imap to dovecot IMAP/POP3 server and i'm having problems with folder listing. In my case i need to configure in the way so all imap/pop3 clients will work with my mailserver like before.

**System**: Dovecot 1.2.11, Gentoo Linux, "maildir" mailbox format. Roundcube 0.4.

**Problem**: Roundcube webmail was working fine before but with dovecot it doesn't find any folders except INBOX. There is how folder list looks for same account:

**Dovecot:**

```
. list "" "*"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Junk"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
. OK List completed.
```

**Courier-imap:**

```
. list "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Drafts"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Trash"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Sent"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Junk"
* LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"
. OK LIST completed
```

I see only two differences there - an order of folders and \Marked attribute. According to IMAPv4 RFC, \Marked only notifies about new messages in that folder and should not affect this.

So, what else can it be?

Folders configuration in Roundcube:

```
$rcmail_config['drafts_mbox'] = 'INBOX.Drafts';
$rcmail_config['junk_mbox'] = 'INBOX.Junk';
$rcmail_config['sent_mbox'] = 'INBOX.Sent';
$rcmail_config['trash_mbox'] = 'INBOX.Trash';
$rcmail_config['default_imap_folders'] = array('INBOX', 'INBOX.Drafts', 'INBOX.Sent', 'INBOX.Junk', 'INBOX.Trash');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to run courier-dovecot-migrate.pl script again because i did that only some time ago. After that, everything works fine. More info - http://wiki.dovecot.org/Migration/Courier